# How to say "I started to learn Java" in Japanese?

Tags: grammar, translation

How to say "I started to learn Java" or "I started to learn Java today"?
Thanks!

Could you say 私はJavaを学び始めた?

Comment: Proofreading questions are off-topic. What is the particular language problem you ask about?

Answer (score 1):

> 私はJavaを学び始めた

You can say that, but this is too formal. I'd say:

> - Javaを（今日）学び始めたよ。 (Friendly)
> - Javaの勉強を（今日）始めました。（Polite）

Answer (score 0):

"I started to learn Java"

1. "私はJavaを学び始めた。"
2. "私はJavaを学び始めました。"
3. "私はJavaの学習をはじめました。"

Any of them ok though personally I choose 3 becuse it sounds softer and  more natural.

"I started to learn Java today"

今日から、{Above sentence here.}

Comment: I think「今日、xxxx」should be ok too? 「今日から、xxxx 」is more like "from today"

Comment: You're right though usually Japanese people don't tell the diffrence between「今日、xxxxをはじめました」and「今日から、xxxxをはじめました」except for a subtle nuance. Usually "今日から" sounds more natural in speaking. "今日、" sounds more decisive in writing. But basically both ok in this case.

Comment: btw, if there aren't "はじめました" then "今日" or "今日から" might give diffrent meaning for sentence...

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the other answers.

Javaを習いはじめた。